# Changing the colour of tabs of Multipage in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I'm using the Forms in VBA and I was wondering if it is possible to make the tabs in my Multipages change colour when active, so that there is a better contrast with the other tabs. Here is a screenshot [image]

Is there a way to *contrast* the active tab from the inactive tabs so that the user can know which tab he is using?

Or do you have any idea so that the active tab can appear better against the inactive tabs?

Comment: You could use another Style ==> use fmTabStyleButtons instead of fmTabStyleTabs, or use none and use normal command buttons

Comment: Posted working alternative using checkmarks :-)

Answer (score 2):

**Approach by marking page captions by a checkmark**

> *"Or do you have any idea so that the active tab can appear better against the inactive tabs?"* -

A possible & helpful approach would be to

- *mark* each clicked page caption by a **checkmark** (e.g. `ChrW(&H2611)`) and to
- automatically *de-mark* a prior page caption: the code *"remembers"* the current/old page index via the multipage's `.Tag` property set at any multipage `..._Change()` event (`.Tag` gets initialized via `UserForm_Initialize()` firstly).

As Captions may include normal blanks, I chose to add a protected blank (`ChrW(&HA0)`) to the checkmark character to allow a simple `Replace()` maintaining the blanks in the original page caption.

**Example code in Userform**

```
Private Sub MultiPage1_Change()
'Purpose: mark current page caption by a checkmark
    With Me.MultiPage1
        Dim pg As MSForms.Page
    'a) de-mark old caption
        Set pg = oldPage(Me.MultiPage1)
        pg.Caption = Replace(pg.Caption, ChkMark, vbNullString)
    'b) mark new caption & remember latest multipage value
        Set pg = .Pages(.Value)
        pg.Caption = ChkMark & pg.Caption
        .Tag = .Value                         ' << remember latest page index
    End With
End Sub
```

**Help functions & `UserForm_Initialize()` routine**

```
Function oldPage(mp As MSForms.MultiPage) As MSForms.Page
'Purpose: return currently marked page in given multipage
    With mp
        Set oldPage = .Pages(Val(.Tag))
    End With
End Function

Function ChkMark() As String
'Purpose: return ballot box with check + blank space
    ChkMark = ChrW(&H2611) & ChrW(&HA0)  ' ballot box with check + blank
End Function

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
'Purpose: mark start page & remember page index
Const startIndx As Long = 0
With Me.MultiPage1
    .Pages(startIndx).Caption = ChkMark & .Pages(startIndx).Caption
    .Tag = startIndx
End With
End Sub
```

[image: Example click on 2nd page]

Answer (score 1):

One method I've used is to rename the tab when activated, and include more space before and after the page name, so that the tab widens when selected for visibility, or surround with <> etc. chars: <<< TAB_NAME >>>.
But lately I've considered using separate buttons to activate a page, and change the color. This saves some screenspace as the multipage itself is shorter, buttons can still look like multipage buttons being on the top left of the multipage, but then all the space to the right is free for other controls.
Actually I use labels setup as command buttonds, generally smaller/less tall.