# Distinguish the tabs for a multipage userform in VBA

Tags: vba, userform, multipage

I saw the following question from another user:

[Changing the colour of tabs of Multipage in VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64696409/changing-the-colour-of-tabs-of-multipage-in-vba)

and it talked about adding a checkmark to the active tab. I'm trying to find something other than that to implement if at all possible.

I actually found mention of a solution which described changing the color of the tabs at the following website:

https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/changing-the-font-back-colors-of-individual-tabs-pages-in-a-multipage.1158211/

but it involves a number of APIs and is rather involved. I'm looking for something perhaps a little simpler.

Answer (score 0):

Okay ... I found a way to accomplish what I was looking to do. Normally tabs appear without anything much distinguishing them as shown below:

[MultiPageTabsRegular](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xEH5K.png)

What I was able to do was make the tabs stand out a little as the following demonstrates:

[MultiPageTabsEnhanced](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a8gSG.png)

This was accomplished by creating a few Labels with the following characteristics:

Delete the Caption

Height = 2

Top = 0

SpecialEffect = 1 – fmSpecialEffectRaised

This was the simplicity I was looking for!

Comment: Could you share your code to demonstrate how to make this work?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

There is no "code" to produce this effect. It's accomplished by creating the appropriate labels and positioning them accordingly.

[Excel Tab UserForm Label 5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b0Kb2.jpg)

[Excel Tab UserForm Label 6](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NuHDa.jpg)

Desired effect:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CPCQa.jpg)